# NHibernate Criteria - How to filter on combination of properties

Tags: nhibernate, expression, icriteria

I needed to filter a list of results using the combination of two properties. A plain SQL statement would look like this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM Person
WHERE FirstName + ' ' + LastName LIKE '%' + @Term + '%'
```

The ICriteria in NHibernate that I ended up using was:

```
ICriteria criteria = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Person));
criteria.Add(Expression.Sql(
    "FirstName + ' ' + LastName LIKE ?",
    "%" + term + "%",
    NHibernateUtil.String));
criteria.SetMaxResults(10);
```

It works perfectly, but I'm not sure if it is the ideal solution since I'm still learning about NHibernate's Criteria API. What are the recommended alternatives?

- Is there something besides `Expression.Sql` that would perform the same operation? I tried `Expression.Like` but couldn't figure out how to combine the first and last names.
- Should I map a FullName property to the formula "FirstName + ' ' + LastName" in the mapping class?
- Should I create a read only FullName property on the domain object then map it to a column?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do one of the following:

- If you always work with the full name, it's probably best to have a single property
- Create a query-only property for that purpose (see http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/06/10/nhibernate-ndash-query-only-properties.aspx)
- Do the query in HQL, which is better suited for free-form queries (it will probably be almost the same as your SQL)
- Use a proper entity-based Criteria:

---

```
Session.CreateCriteria<Person>()
       .Add(Restrictions.Like(
            Projections.SqlFunction("concat",
                                    NHibernateUtil.String,
                                    Projections.Property("FirstName"),
                                    Projections.Constant(" "),
                                    Projections.Property("LastName")),
            term,
            MatchMode.Anywhere))
```

Comment: Query-only - how very useful, didn't know about that option. Seems like I learn something new every day in NHibernate. Thanks for the Projections code sample too.

Answer (score 0):

On the pure technical side i don't have an answer, but consider this:
since you are only have a single input field for the user to enter the term, you don't know if he is going to enter 'foo bar' or 'bar foo'... so i would recommend this:

```
ICriteria criteria = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Person));
criteria.Add(Expression.Like("FirstName",term, MatchMode.Anywhere) || Expression.Like("LastName",term, MatchMode.Anywhere));
criteria.SetMaxResults(10);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Originally I tried that but people were typing in "john smi" and expecting to see John Smith pop up.

Comment: I handle this case by looking if there is no space I match against first or last if there is a space I then split the search string and search against the first and last again.